# Autostart several fully-functional consoles on windows

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm Node.js developer.
1) Every time I restart my computer I have to run 6 cmd windows with various command-line services (in --watch mode).
2) I need to see the output from this commands: sometimes there are errors, that I need to know and correct.
3) There are many times when I want to stop and later - restart some of this cmds'. I do this with Ctrl+C - to stop, and than - Up arrow, Enter to run again.

I want to automate it.
I tried creating some autorun commands (.bat, windows services, etc), but this isn't good because ether I can't run them automatically or I can't stop/restart them as easy as Ctrl+C, Up arrow, Enter, or they show no console output. For now I use

```
cmd /k
```

But this thing doesn't save the autostarted command, so I can't restart it with Up arrow, Enter.

Is there a tool or some tricks which can do 1+2+3 ?

Comment: [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) offers most, if not all, of what you're looking for

Comment: As far as I've tested - it can't autorun. How do I do that?

Comment: You can add ConEmu in Task Scheduler to start at login and under ConEmu's Settings > Startup - Tasks, create 6 separate cmd terminal tasks for the 6 windows you need, then configure them to all launch upon launching ConEmu.  You should also be able to configure 6 cmd windows to auto-launch at login via Task Scheduler, but ConEmu is more customizable and will likely serve to be more helpful in general.  I can't give you the specific steps on how to configure this in ConEmu, but ConEmu offers extensive help documentation

Comment: I tried it just now. It can start tasks, but it doesn't remember the last command it ran in autostart, so it can't do (3 - stop/restart)

Comment: That's a command history issue I've also experienced and there's likely a reason for this and a way to address it within ConEmu's [man page](https://conemu.github.io/en/TableOfContents.html).  99% of the time it populates the command history without issue, then every now and then doesn't.  Another option would be Microsoft's new [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701) app, which is fairly customizable, but I haven't spent enough time trying to yet.  Are you starting it under your user account or Admin's in Task Scheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no answers for quite a long time, so I've created a tool for Node.js developers.
Here it is:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/my_wins

This answer is likely valid only for Node.js developers...